# How to configure rails in Intellij Idea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, intellij-idea

I have a IntelliJ Idea 11 with Ruby Plugin installed. Im trying to configure a project but the IDE doesn't recognize my views as a module. It just adds other folders (controllers, db, config)
Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Cant see views here nor in my project]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried asking the IntelliJ mailing list or forum about why this could happen?

Comment: I don't even see that, I just have a single "Ruby on Rails" module.

Comment: @DaveNewton i think i was doing it wrong im new in ruby... now with the CrazyCoder answer, I have a single Ruby on Rails module too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new project using a wizard for the root of your rails application (from scratch, Ruby module, add **Ruby on Rails** facet, **Use existing Rails application**):

[image: use existing rails application]

Comment: Thats worked... now i have just one module(my root folder) is that right?
I have 2 projects in ruby and one in python that is related to this project, can i add them all as a single project with 3 modules in ruby and one in python?

Comment: That's right, you can add more modules with Python and Ruby code to the same project (`File` | `Add Module`).

Comment: Note to others who want to do this: You have to select the directory of the preexisting code during the creation of the "new" project. There won't be any obvious indication that IDEA will be using the existing code, but it will.